# Shift values in dataframe to the left if column name == Year and value is NaN pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                              0    1   2018       3   2017       5
0                    Population    3    NaN  418980    NaN  501433
1                       British    4  31514     NaN  96797     NaN
2                        French  NaN   3089     NaN    201     NaN
3                           NaN  NaN  34603     NaN  96998     NaN
```

I want to end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                              0    1   2018       3   2017       5
0                    Population    3  418980    NaN  501433    NaN
1                       British    4  31514     NaN  96797     NaN
2                        French  NaN   3089     NaN    201     NaN
3                           NaN  NaN  34603     NaN  96998     NaN
```

Where the logic is: 
If a year column has a NaN value, look to the right for a numerical value and replace the NaN value.

I believe I need to find the index of any year column, look for `df['2018'].isnull()`, if it is null, add one to the index then search for the corresponding value but am unsure if this is the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is replace next values of years to years with forward filling misisng values and then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `axis=1` for grouping per columns and get first non missing values if exist by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
s = df.columns.astype(str).to_series()
a = s.where(s.str.contains('\d{4}')).ffill().fillna(s)
print (a)
0          0
1          1
2018    2018
3       2018
2017    2017
5       2017
dtype: object

df1 = df.groupby(pd.Index(a), axis=1).first()
print (df1)
         0     1         2017      2018
0  Population   3.0  501433.0  418980.0
1     British   4.0   96797.0   31514.0
2      French   NaN     201.0    3089.0
3         NaN   NaN   96998.0   34603.0
```

Comment: Will it also work if the next column doesn't have a value, or will it then take the value from the next column, which I assume is not what the OP meant?

Comment: Just checking through this one now!

Comment: @Aryerez - If not exist next column values then it test another column until another year.

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` has a built in function for using another column to replace the `NA` values in the original :

```
df[2018] = df[2018].combine_first(df[3])
```

If you have many columns like that, think how to loop over the columns to use the column name and it's right-sided one's name. (or I can help you with that)

Comment: Damn pandas has everything, I just didn't know the function! Thanks a lot. I'll try working on it myself for a bit and respond here if I need help!

Answer (score 0):

By using what @Aryerez answered with I came up with this:

```py
columns_list = list(df.columns) 
year_column_indexes = [i for i, item in enumerate(columns_list) if re.search('201[0-9]', item)]
for _index in year_column_indexes:
    df.iloc[:, _index] = df.iloc[:, _index].combine_first(df.iloc[:, _index+1])
    df = df.drop(df.columns[_index+1], axis=1)
```

But it needs a bit of editing.

Comment: Why editing? What don't you like about it? (I would do it a bit different, but not neccesary better)

Comment: When I drop the column, `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. It needs to drop `_index+1` then the next iteration needs to be `_index` then the next iteration `_index-1` and so on...

Comment: In the requested output of the question you didn't drop the columns between the years, so I didn't pay attention to that...

Comment: Fair enough! I do need to do that!